# traefik route configuration with http and https

Tags: traefik, api-gateway, traefik-ingress

Our web application is already running on on-prem Kubernetes setup with the following traefik configuration. The HTTPS endpoints are working fine, and now we need to add two services that run on HTTP with their own specific ports.

So basically we need to do the following routing:

```
[existing setup]
HTTPS adminapp.mydomain.com -> Admin UI App
HTTPS myapp.mydomain.com -> UI App
HTTPS api.mydomain.com -> Backend API

[new services]
HTTP api.mydomain.com:8111 -> Service1 API Integration with HTTP
HTTP api.mydomain.com:9111 -> Service2 API Integration with HTTP
```

Service1 and Service2 are intranet systems that will send the data to their own specific ports.

Here is the traefik configuration:

```
## Entrypoint Configurations
entryPoints:
  web:
    address: ":80"

  websecure:
    address: ":443"

  service1:
    address: ":8111"
 
  service2:
    address: ":9111"

----
## Service1 IngressRoute 

  entryPoints:
    - service1
  routes:
  - match: Host(`api.mydomain.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: service1-clusterip-service
      port: 8111

----
## Service2 IngressRoute 

  entryPoints:
    - service2
  routes:
  - match: Host(`api.mydomain.com`)
    kind: Rule
    services:
    - name: service2-clusterip-service
      port: 9111
```

When we try to call the Service1 service with the following API `http://api.mydomain.com:8111/path/arg/item` over the HTTP request, getting this specific error.

```
upstream connect error or disconnect/reset before headers. reset reason: connection failure, transport failure reason: delayed connect error: 111
```

There is not much detail in the `access logs` as well to identify where the request is breaking.

We have a middleware to force redirect from HTTP to HTTPS, but that is removed to test the above configurations.

Any idea on why the configuration is not working as expected!!

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. We found a typo in the service that was pointing to the wrong pod selector.

Also, our setup changed a bit so putting it here if anyone else faces the same issue.

[existing setup]

- HTTPS adminapp.mydomain.com -> Admin UI App
- HTTPS myapp.mydomain.com -> UI App
- HTTPS api.mydomain.com -> Backend API

[new services]

- HTTP api.mydomain.com:8111 -> Service1 API Integration with HTTP
- TCP api.mydomain.com:9111 -> Service2 API Integration with TCP

For TCP integration make sure you follow these:

- Entrypoint is defined with `:port/tcp`
- Router is defined with IngressRouterTCP
- If you are doing then host check, then use the **HostSNI(`*`)** if tls is disabled.